# Evaluate $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^nx\cos nx\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^nx\cos nxdx$ where $n$ is a positive integer. The choices are

a.$\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}$

b.$\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}$

c.$\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}$

d.$\frac{3\pi}{2^{n}}$

e. None of these

**My approach:**

$$e^{inx}=\cos nx+i\sin nx$$

$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^nx\cos nx\,dx$ = Real part of $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^nxe^{inx}\,dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\cos xe^{ix})^n\,dx$

After this step I am not able to approach.

Comment: $e^{inx}$ is also $(\cos x + i \sin x)^n$.  Could that help?

Comment: I understand you want to proceed with your approach, but there are so many other near-duplicates, including one that uses exponential identities, that the site would be better off without your question.